# Is it possible to invoke AWS Lambda function from SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, aws-lambda

Does anyone know how to invoke a AWS Lambda function from an SQL Server instance stored procedure in AWS RDS?

Comment: In what language? Do you have a piece of code for that function that people can go through rather than trying to write all from zero?

Comment: I have a test lambda that I have written in Python which will take an XML format and parse the data into an email that will be sent via AWS SES.  I cannot figure out how to invoke the lambda from the SQL stored procedure that generates the XML

Comment: @CrashOverride Are you *sure* MySQL can call Lambda functions and not just Aurora?

Comment: @CrashOverride looks like only [Aurora MySQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html) can connect to Lambda. Even Aurora Postgress [doesn't support this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Integrating.html)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Apologies. Typo.  Corrected now!!!!

Answer (score -1):

The following talks about calling a Lambda function from Oracle or PostgreSQL database. Maybe it can provide some details for you to move forward.

[From SQL to Microservices: Integrating AWS Lambda with Relational Databases](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/from-sql-to-microservices-integrating-aws-lambda-with-relational-databases/) by Bob Strahan

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: He asked explicitly for RDS, that article is for a Postgres installed on an EC2 instance...