# How to invoke AWS Lambda function from RDS SQL Server Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

How can I invoke an AWS Lambda function from an Amazon RDS SQL Server database as the last step of stored procedure?

Comment: It does not look like this is possible: [amazon web services - Is it possible to invoke AWS Lambda function from SQL Server stored procedure? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823700/is-it-possible-to-invoke-aws-lambda-function-from-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Comment: I think there are some limitations in RDS SQL Server. read this https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2021/07/aws-rds-sql-server-limitations.html

Comment: Is there any updates on this issue?